# Set display:inline to a div results in zero width and height

Tags: html, css

So I am having a very simple markup like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="foo">
  <div>a</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
.foo {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But this makes div.foo to have 0 width and 0 height. If I set display to `inline-block`, it works. Why?
Here is the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ruvaq/1/edit?html,css,output) of this post.

Comment: the `width` and `height` is applied only to `block` or `inline-block` element, inline element will have size depending on only `margin` and the content. that's by design, so there is no answer for why. Of course that's the most difference between inline and block.

Comment: @KingKing - the height of inline elements is also affected by line-height.

Comment: @BryanDowning ah yeah, miss that.

Comment: @BryanDowning Thx man! But it is so wired that it does not just ignore it.

Comment: the size of inline element also depends on the `letter-spacing` and `word-spacing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a `<div>` is a block element you must specify it's width and height or it wil be wrapped arround the content inside the `<div>` element.

And indeed changing it's display to `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` changes his normal behaviour.